# Acronym finder regex building with perl

Tags: regex, perl

Having `N` defined words, for this question 3 words e.g.: `open` `icebreaker` `umbrela`.

Wondering than is here any possible acronym what exists as english word, e.g. want run something like:

```
grep -Pi '^o(p(e?))?i(c(e?))?um?$' my_long_wordlist.txt
```

in the above regex I decided then i can use

- from the 1st word `o`, or `op` or `ope` (first, or first two, or first three letters)
- from the 2nd word `i`, or `ic` or `ice` (first, or first two, or first three letters)
- and finally form the last word I can use only first or firtst two letters - `u` or `um`

for the fun - the above regex will return for me the word: `opium` :)

Constructing regexes *by hand* is acceptable for one two tests, but i want check many word combinatons, so, looking for a way how to generating regexes as above.

Want build an "acronym finder regex script" with following calling:

```
acrobuild open:4 icebreaker:3 umbrela:3
```

As you can see, the the args are the words, and the number after the delimiter is the *maximum* number of letter from the beginning what can be used in the acronym.

Now the question - i'm fully lost how to build the regex for the given length. Need some hint, idea or like.. - check "NEED HELP HERE" :)

Currently I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;

do_grep(  make_regex(@ARGV) );
exit;

sub make_regex {
    my(@words) = @_;
    my $regex;
    foreach my $wordnum (@words) {
        $regex .= make_word_regex( split(/:/, $wordnum) );
    }
    $regex = '^' . $regex . '$' if $regex;
    return $regex;
}

sub make_word_regex {
    my($word, $num) = @_;

    return "" unless $word;
    $num = length($word) unless defined($num);  #for make legal -> word:0

    my(@chars) = split(//, substr($word,0,$num) );

    #regex building x  or   xy?  or  x(y(z?))? etc... :(
    my $re = "";
    foreach my $c (reverse(@chars)) {   #reverse, to building inside-out
        # HOW TO BUILD THE REGEX HERE?
        # NEED HELP HERE
    }
    return($re);
}

sub do_grep {
    my($re) = @_;
    say "$re"; return; #tmp
    my $recomp = qr/$re/i;

    open(my $fdict, "<", "/usr/share/dict/web2") or die("No dict file $!");
    while(<$fdict>) {
        chomp;
        say $_ if m/$recomp/;
    }
    close($fdict);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a nested regexp `o(p(e?)?)`, I would just make a list of alternates: `(o|op|ope)`.

```
sub make_regex_word {
    my ($word)=@_;
    my ($base,$count)=split(/:/,$word);
    my @chars=split(//,$base);
    my @re=();
    for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
        push @re,join("",@chars[0..$i]);
    }
    return "(".join("|",@re).")";
}
```

Comment: Very nice simplification of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are generally on the right track. I would implement `make_word_regex` like this:

```
my ($word, $num) = @_;

# paranoid error checking
defined $word         or croak "Can't prepare undef value";
$num <= length($word) or croak "More characters requested than avaliable";
$num >= 1             or croak "Pattern must consist of at least one char";

my $regex = ''; # initialize $regex to something we can interpolate w/o warning

for my $char (reverse split //, substr $word, 0, $num) {
  # use qr// instead of treating regexes like strings
  # The \Q ... \E protects for special characters. Always use this for external input.
  $regex = qr/\Q$char\E $regex?/x; 
}

return $regex;
```

This works as expected, save for the fact that a lot of unneccessary junk is included inside the regex (`make_word_regex("open", 3)` returns a regex object that may stringify to `(?x-ism:o (?x-ism:p (?x-ism:e ?)?)?)`, depending on your perl).

You can combine these partial regexes to an acronym finder in a similar way. I'd write `make_regex` as

```
# assert that every word is followed by a number.
@_ % 2 == 0 or croak "even number of arguments required.";

my @regexes;
while (@_) {
  my ($word, $num) = splice @_, 0, 2; # shift the first two elems
  push @regexes, make_word_regex($word, $num);
}

# combine the regexes:
return qr/ \A  @regexes \z /x;
```

The `\A` anchores at the beginning of the string; `\z` at the end. The `/x` flag allows make regexes more readable by including non-matching whitespace.

You could then invoke the script like

```
$ acrobuild open 3 icebreaker 3 umbrella 2
```

I would advise against hardcoding a dictionary file. Pipe the dict through STDIN instead:

```
$ acrobuild open 3 icebreaker 3 umbrella 2 </usr/share/dict/web2
```

This would simplify your `do_grep` to

```
my $re = shift;
while (<STDIN>) {
  chomp;
  say if /$re/i;
}
```

Comment: Accepting the another answer because he simplyfied the problem to alternations. thank you anyway +1!